# Cached Exchange Mode and BlackBerry/BES

Tags: outlook, blackberry

We have some BlackBerry synchronization problems. A Google search of "Cached Exchange Mode and BlackBerry", but I can't really find a definitive answer. Is there anybody here who has tested this and has a definitive answer? Can I use Cached Exchange Mode in combination with BlackBerry/BES?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Cached Exchange Mode in Outlook with BES.  What synchronization problems are you experiencing?

Comment: Dear Xeon, thank you for your reply. The BlackBerry and the Outlook on the workstations are not always in sync. So sometimes or with some users there is no problem, but at another time email actions are missing on either the workstation or the BlackBerry. We already did a lot of troubleshooting in combination with the eventlogs and until now we have not solved it. However there is a strong indication that the Cached Exchange Mode is the cause. Have you used BES in combination with Cached Exchange Mode?

Comment: Yes, using it right now.  Exchange 2007 with BES 5.0.  All Outlook 2007 clients are using Exchange Cached Mode and a lot of mailboxes over 5GB.  Works without a hitch.  Obviously your client needs to sync with Exchange server before it hits the BB.  Maybe your clients are not syncing to Exchange when they have updates?  Check your BES logs for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your BES software is up-to-date. The BES use to have some problems with BB sync'ing when Exchange Cached Mode was enabled especially with reoccuring meetings.  These issues were all fixed quite some time ago though.

Answer (score 0):

This actually has to do with Anti-virus software and BES conflicting, since once Outlook receives a copy of the e-mail, your anti-virus program will mark the message as scanned.  BES also does something to this degree, as it marks the message as sent.  Since BES is making changes directly to the copy on the mail store, and your anti-virus is making changes to the copy in your local cached mailbox, a conflict occurs.